# Bootstrap navbar toggle not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am currently building a website using Bootstrap and have gotten stock on the implementation part. I've checked and it appears I've installed Bootstrap and Jquery correctly, but when I go to toggle the dropdown menu on a mobile sized screen nothing happens. I understand this has been asked before and have tried to resolve my issue with those solutions but nothing helped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Portfolio</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
        <!--- Brand and toggle grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">Test</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" datatarget=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>



                <!-- Body content below -->


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" id="#">
                <h1> Test</h1>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Jquery Library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<nav class='navbar-default navbar' >
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a dash to the `datatarget=".navbar-collapse"` it should look like `data-target=".navbar-collapse"`

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.